# How to configure a 2nd router to act as VPN gateway

Tags: networking, vpn, gateway

i need to configure a new router with DD-WRT, in my network, configured as gateway VPN.

My main gateway router is configured with ip Address 192.168.1.254, Subnet 255.255.255.0. 
It act also as DHCP that release 192.168.1.x address class.

The 2nd router with DD-WRT is configured with ip address 192.168.1.10. 
Then i configure VPN as described like image 2. 
The Problem is both pc1 or pc2 if configured with gateway 192.168.1.10 can't go on internet.

What am i missing ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which router is configured to do NAT for them? If neither, then of course it won't work.

Comment: Ok, but if i configure a PPTP VPN directly on  PC4 for example, it works. So i assume that my Gateway allow natively vpn.

Comment: For its clients, sure. But PC1 and PC2 aren't its clients.

Comment: But this means that main 'Router Gateway' (not DD WRT) allow PPTP connections (because if i use a PC with a software vpn configured, it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. 
Simply, the problem, was the version installed of DD-WRT. I tried another version and worked without any problem.
So there aren't any networking problem.

Answer (score 1):

From your gateway router, you must poke a few holes in the firewall, and possibly enable some firewall modules.  From the picture you posted, it looks like you're trying to setup `l2tp`, which usually is mixed with `IPSEC`.  Both of which require forwarding more than just a few ports.  `IPSEC` requires 2 protocols to be permitted through, as well as a port.  You must permit `AH` (protocol 51) as well as `ESP` (protocol 50) as well as udp port 500.  Openwrt has a [great wiki page](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall#ipsec.passthrough) just for that.

If your gateway router is not running openwrt, usually you can find an option labled "ipsec passthrough," "vpn passthrough" or something similar.  In openwrt, you'll need to install the `iptables-mod-ipsec` package to permit iptables to keep track of ipsec connections.  (Without it, you will be limited to 1 connection)

Once `IPSEC` is permitted in, `l2tp` will make use of the encrypted data stream to tunnel layer 2 communications between the endpoints.